# extract two columns: Language and COUNT(*)(indicates no of diff language), rank the frequency of languages in decreasing order

Tags: mysql

SELECT
language,
COUNT(*)
FROM
countrylanguage
GROUP BY
language
ORDER BY language DESC;

This is the query that i tried but the error shows :

MySQL said:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT language COUNT(*) FROM countrylanguage GROUP BY language ORDER BY language' at line 2

Comment: `LANGUAGE` is a non reserved MySQL keyword, [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L).  Try putting it in backticks.

Comment: it kept on showing error so i used `SELECT Language,COUNT(Language) FROM countrylanguage GROUP BY Language ORDER BY COUNT(Language) DESC;` and finally it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT Language,COUNT(Language) FROM countrylanguage GROUP BY Language ORDER BY COUNT(Language) DESC;`